# Create a new object from existing pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, syntax, copy-constructor, auto-ptr

I've looked for the answer but still can't figure this out.

Sorry, but my work is too complex to copy here sample code.

I have a function, which gets a pointer as parameter; I use it, but later, I need a kind of callback, where I want to use my old pointed object.

The problem is, when this callback is invoked, the pointer has already been deleted or freed. My idea was to make a copy of the pointed object on the heap, and free it when callback is finished. But I got lost between pointers, copy constructors and other stuff. The solution is probably quite simple, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a type `T`, and a pointer `T* ptr;`  Assuming `ptr` is currently a valid pointer, then `T* ptr2 = new T(*ptr);` should invoke the copy constructor on T to create a new pointer on the heap.  Now, this requires that your type `T` has a correctly written copy constructor and destructor and the like.

Comment: I was sure, that is should use copy constructor, but the how-to wasnt clear. Ill try it!

Comment: Okay, I see whats the next problem:
<code>
 cannot allocate an object of abstract type#
 because the following virtual functions are pure within
<code>

Comment: So you don't actually have an object of type T.  You have an object of a subclass of type T.  The only reasonable way to clone this object is if the T interface includes a clone() type method that does it for you.

Comment: You say something... :D I'll try write this clone(), but not sure, what sould exactly write into..

Comment: `virtual T* clone() const` is the traditional `clone()` signature.  Subtypes override it and return a pointer to the subtype, which lets you clone an instance of the object even if you don't know the type.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a `T * p`, then you can make a new object like so:

```
T x(*p);
```

Or, if you must (but seriously, don't!), a dynamically allocated object:

```
T * q = new T(*p);
```

Don't use the second form. There's no end to the headache you're inviting with that.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
MyObject* pointerFromOld;
...
MyObject newObject = *pointerFromOld;
```

Asterisk before a pointer returns the object it points to (interprets the contents of the address as the object), while assigning that object to newObject makes its copy.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this:
[C++ Idioms/Virtual Constructor](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor)